# Unable to open playground business network with redeclared variable

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm currently playing around with Hyperledger Composer in their playground environment, working on the "Web Browser" connection as i'm just testing and playing around with it.

**What did i do?**

I accidentally copied a part of a js file into another js file, which declares a variable with the same name twice.

File 1 declares a MAX_ID_LENGHT variable and File 2 also declares a MAX_ID_LENGHT variable.

I didn't took notice that also had that variable added to my second file, so i adjusted some transactions and functions to work a little diffirent then the once in the other file.

After that i pressed "Deploy" again.

**What is the problem?**

After hitting "deploy" i got the error:

```
SyntaxError: redeclaration of let MAX_ID_LENGTH
```

**What did i try to solve it?**

- When removing the redeclaration from File 2 and hitting "deploy" again i got the same error again.
- When removing the variable also from the other file and making it a static value, it also gave the same error.
- When refreshing "f5" it gives the same error but doesn't show me any files anymore.
- Restarted Composer playground without any luck.
- Restarted Fabric without any luck.

Does anybody have any solutions to get access to the playground network again or does somebody know where the files are stored from the "Web Browser" connection in Ubuntu Linux?

Thanks in advance,

Noah

### UPDATE

I could not find a proper solution, and did not spend to much time on going through my local storage in the Firefox folder.

Eventually just went to an older back-up and added the written logic back in from there.

Answer (score 0):

When installed locally, on the Playground 'My Business Networks' page you see your Business Network cards arranged in 2 groups:

1. Connection: hlfv1
2. Connection: Web Browser

The Web Browser section allows you to develop/test and 'deploy' Business Networks all within the context of the Browser, connecting to a simulated Fabric within the Browser, and storing everything in the Browser local storage.  This can be a volatile store and data can be easily lost here.

If you used the 'Connection: hlfv1' then you would have been connected to as 'real' Fabric, and you can retrieve your Business Network from the Fabric, and your Business networks should be available.

Ignoring the Playground for the moment, you can try the following command to see if you have Cards available - `composer card list`, and you can use this command to retrieve the Business Network definition from the Fabric `composer network download`.

For Firefox on Ubuntu, the localstorage is somewhere under ~/.mozilla/firefox but navigating through is likely to take longer than re-creating the Business Network.

I know it is too late now, but when working with the Playground in localstorage, regular exports of the Business Network are advisable.

Comment: It's no big problem, as i frequently exported it already.
However it seems weird that you get completely locked out if you define the same variable name twice, you'd still expect to be able to change it in the playground editor.